# Mapping for maze solving robot

Tags: mapping, path-planning, beginner, occupancy-grid

I'm trying to implement a program to find the shortest path for a maze solving robot competition but I can't understand how to do the mapping.

I tried Breadth first Search algorithm that takes in a 2D map but how do I convert the sensor data into a binary occupancy map and then use that as the map?

For the sensors, We're using 2 ultrasonic sensors and 3 active IR sensors.

Comment: What do you mean by "active IR sensors"? Realsense cameras?

Comment: @MartinPecka by "active IR sensors" I mean the normal IR sensor, so not the passive IR sensor.

Comment: Hmm, normal can mean many things :) So you mean the thing with a projector and a photoresistor, whose output is a single number?

Comment: @MartinPecka yes, that's the one

Comment: Okay. Building a map just from ultrasonic and these simple IR sensors is actually a quite demanding task, if not impossible. Could you please edit the question and clarify whether you get the 2D map from the organizers and need just to localize in it, or if the map should be constructed by your robot? Also, is the starting position and orientation known?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Miriam, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.